# How to completely uninstall USB DEVICE (i.e. mouse or keyboard) driver?

Tags: windows, usb, drivers, uninstall

Is there any way or utility to COMPLETELY uninstall & remove the device driver with all it's traces?

details: I plugged a new USB MOUSE (EasySMX), everything worked well in the beggining (without any need to install a driver). However, i've additionally installed "recommended driver" software for that mouse, but after that mouse started to misbehave (specifically, lags 1 seconds once in 10 seconds). Have tried all uninstall methods (control panel, device manager, restarting pc, etc..), but still problem with that mouse. I want to uninstall everything related to that.

Comment: What mous? What driver? What ways have you tried?

Comment: *Have tried all uninstall methods (device manager, restarting pc, etc..)* there is a curious absence in this list of the normal uninstall procudure for any program. (via control panel)

Comment: Just making sure. Sometimes it is the really obvious part which gets missed.

Comment: ok, question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to Device Manager and doubleclick the hardware you want to uninstall, you can go to the "Driver" tab, click "Uninstall device", then mark the checkbox to also delete that driver.

But maybe you already knew that (this is not clear by your post). If this doesn't solve your issue, I'd try changing your mouse DPI and it's refresh rate.

## Edit:

Answering to your further questions:

Looks like the checkbox I was talking about ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAn3L.png)) doesn't show for all devices. I don't know why this happens, but it could be because the driver you are trying to delete is a standard driver embbedded in Windows. Anyway, here is a possible alternative you could try to delete the driver:

Go to **Device Manager** or alternatively run the command (WindowsKey + R):

> devmgmt.msc

Right-click the device you need to uninstall and go to **Properties**. Select the **Details** tab and then select **INF Name** from the drop-down list.

Once you have the INF Name, type in this command in a command window opened with Admin privileges:

> pnputil.exe -d *INFName.inf*

If you face issues try forced deletion:

> pnputil.exe -f -d *INFName.inf*

**About DPI and refresh rate:** you can't change them through Windows' Control Panel. You must do it through the software controller that came with your mouse (if it has one) or through it's hardware interface (by clicking the mouse buttons, as you said).

I suspected of DPI and refresh rate because I already saw this kind of problem being caused by them! Sometimes a specific DPI or (specially) a different refresh rate causes this kind of trouble! And this could explain why rolling back the driver didn't solve your issue.

Also, it could be a good idea to test your mouse on another computer, just to be sure it's not a hardware issue.

I really hope you find a solution, good luck!

Comment: Since this comment field has character limitation, I edited my original answer. Please, read it.